# Is there any way to get the size in bytes of each database of a Bigquery project?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run a script in bigquery where I find the size of all databases in a given project.

Comment: When you say script, are you referring to a programming language or sql statements

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE` view.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#table_storage_view

```sql
SELECT project_id, table_schema, SUM(total_logical_bytes) AS total_logical_bytes
  FROM `region-asia-northeast3`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE
 GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 3 DESC
;
```

output:

[image]